# Getting the associated table content inside the json given to angular by rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, associations

I am using angular with rails,inside which I have an index.html.erb page which hits a controller action

```
def index
@listings=Listing.all
end
```

/*app.js*/

```
var app = angular.module("PetForLife", ['ngResource']);
```

I am passing this @listings to my angular controller through the init method.

Now the issue is this listing table has an association with photos table which stores the multiple photos associated with every listing, so in short I have

/*Listing.rb*/

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :photos
end
```

/*Photo.rb*/

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :file_name, PhotoUploader
    belongs_to :listing
end
```

My angular controller is code is

/*ListingController.js*/

```
app.controller('ListingController', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.post = "Angular Rocks!"

    $scope.init = function(listings)
    {
            $scope.listings = angular.fromJson(listings)

    }

    $scope.clear = function(){

        delete $scope.listing1.breed_type;

    }
    $scope.clearAll = function(){

        delete $scope.listing1;

    }

}]);
```

/*index.html.erb*/

```
<div ng-controller="ListingController">
<div class="ui divided items" ng-init="init(<%=@listings.to_json %>)">
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="listing in listings | filter:{'gender':listing1.gender,'pet_type':listing1.pet_type,'breed_type':listing1.breed_type}:true">

      <div class="image">

      </div>
      <div class="content listing_content">
        <i class="right floated large like icon"></i>
        <i class="right floated large star icon"></i>

        <%=link_to '{{listing.title}}','{{listing.id}}',class:'header'%>
        <div class="meta">
          <span class="cinema">Posted On
          <%@date = '{{listing.created_at}}'  %>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
          {{listing.love_for_pets}}
        </div>


        <div class="extra listing_price">
          <div class="right floated ui circular facebook icon button">
            <i class="facebook icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="right floated ui circular twitter icon button">
            <i class="twitter icon"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="right floated ui circular google plus icon button">
            <i class="google plus icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="ui teal tag label"><i class="rupee icon"></i>{{listing.price}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  </div>
```

In the index.html.erb file,

I want to do something like this

```
<%=image_tag listing.photos.first.file_name.url%>
```

But since angular has this listing as a json, that association is not found.

How can i implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you need to use something like `@listings.to_json(:include => :photos)` 
instead of `@listings.to_json` to include assocition into json.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what i was looking for.Just a minor question,why this aint working <%=image_tag '{{listing.photos[0].file_name.url}}',class:'ui medium image',style:'border-radius:5px;max-width:100%'%>

Comment: ok so i found a workaround for this, I am using the normal img html tags instead of the image_tag of rails.Still if you have a solution for this using rails image_tag then please let me know.Thanks and I am marking your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Under the hood image_tag uses a lot of assets-related functions, to ensure that generated <img> tag is valid and points to image. It might be better for you, to use simple <img> tag or to generate page content by angular templates.